# A value must be provided for item. Logics App

Tags: excel, azure, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to update a row in Excel if the value in a column meets a cetain condition. However, I am getting this error.

> "status": 400,   "message": "A value must be provided for
> item.\r\nclientRequestId: aef52407-6469-4f60-9265-0715a0ab7dd1",
> "error": {
> "message": "A value must be provided for item."

[image]

The value I want to update is in the column named `Amount`. It says the key column takes a string, so I have given the column name and I have put the value I want in it. Not sure what wrong I am doing here.

Comment: What’s the value of **Body**?

Comment: @Skin It should have been pre-populated. Basically the Column names should have been already there and then I needed to specify which row's value I needed to change. So, The above is not the correct form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reproducing the issue from my end, I understood that this is because the Logic app somehow couldn't be able to find the location of the exact cell that you trying to update. Below is how I could able to make it work.

**NOTE:** Make sure your data is stored in a table in your excel file and then, you can choose the required table directly from the dropdown option.

[image]

For Key Column and Key Value, select the unique Column (Header) and value of that particular table for the row that you want the update.

[image]

Now, from **Add new parameters** you can select the columns of that particular row that you want to update.

[image]

[image]

**RESULTS:**

***Before Run:***

[image]

***After Run:***

[image]

Comment: In my case, the table fields were not getting populated. That was the issue. This answer is correct.